# what is the use of external IP address with a ClusterIP service type in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

What is the use of external IP address option in kubernetes service when the service is of type `ClusterIP`

Comment: Can you show an example of external ClusterIP?

Answer (score 2):

[ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) is the default service type in Kubernetes which allows you to reach your service only **within** the cluster.

If your service type is set as [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) or [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport), `ClusterIP` is automatically created and `LoadBalancer` or `NodePort` service will route to this `ClusterIP` IP address.

The new external IP addresses are only allocated with `LoadBalancer` type.

You can also use the node's external IP addresses when you set your service as `NodePort`. But in this case you will need extra firewall rules for your nodes to allow ingress traffic for your exposed node ports.

Answer (score 1):

An `ExternalIP` is just an endpoint through which services can be accessed from outside the cluster, so a `ClusterIP` type service with an `ExternalIP` can still be accessed inside the cluster using its service.namespace DNS name, but now it can also be accessed from its external endpoint, too. For instance, you could set the `ExternalIP` to the IP of one of your k8s nodes, or create an ingress to your cluster on that IP.

Comment: Hi,  is it good idea to give nodeIP as a externalIP to the pod ?

Comment: That's a good question @SureshVishnoi. IMO its bad practice if multinode cluster.

Comment: @Hrishikesh  yea there are possibilities of downtime of nodes. I think ExternalIP should come from another subnet and routed to multiple nodes of the k8s clster.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using service with `type: ClusterIP` it has only Cluster IP and no external IP address `<none>`.

Answer (score 0):

ClusterIP is unique Ip given from IP pool to a service and to access pods of this service cluster IP can be used only inside a cluster.Cluster IP is default service type in kubernetes.

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --target-port=80 --type=LoadBalancer
```

above example will create a service with external IP and cluster IP.
In case of loadbalancer,nodeport services ,the service can be accessed from other clusters through externalIP

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to coolinuxoid answer. I'm working with GKE and based on their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps) when you add a Service of type ClusterIP they offer to access it via:

> Accessing your Service
> List your running Pods:
>
> kubectl get pods
>
> In the output, copy one of the Pod names that begins with
> my-deployment.
>
> NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
> my-deployment-dbd86c8c4-h5wsf   1/1     Running   0          2m51s
>
> **Get a shell into one of your running containers:**
>
> **kubectl exec -it pod-name -- sh**
>
> **where pod-name is the name of one of the Pods in my-deployment.**
>
> **In your shell, install curl:**
>
> **apk add --no-cache curl**
>
> In the container, make a request to your Service by using your cluster
> IP address and port 80. Notice that 80 is the value of the port field
> of your Service. This is the port that you use as a client of the
> Service.
>
> curl cluster-ip:80
> So, while you might find a way to route to such a Service from outside, it's not a recommended/ordinary way to do it.

As a better alternative either use:

1. `LoadBalancer` if you are working on a project with a lot of services and detailed requirements.
2. `NodePort` if you are working on something smaller where cloud-native load balancing is not needed and you don't mind using your node's IP directly to map it to the Service. Incidentally, the same document does suggest an option to do so(tested it personally; works like a charm):

> If the nodes in your cluster have external IP addresses, find the
> external IP address of one of your nodes:
>
> kubectl get nodes --output wide
>
> The output shows the external IP addresses of your nodes:
>
> NAME          STATUS    ROLES     AGE    VERSION        EXTERNAL-IP
> gke-svc-...   Ready     none      1h     v1.9.7-gke.6   203.0.113.1
>
> Not all clusters have external IP addresses for nodes. For example,
> the nodes in private clusters do not have external IP addresses.
>
> **Create a firewall rule to allow TCP traffic on your node port:**
>
> **gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-node-port --allow**
> **tcp:node-port**
>
> **where: node-port is the value of the nodePort field of your Service.**